# Facebook Marketing API - Ads billing transactions

Tags: facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I need to pull up a list of ad transactions on business billing (business.facebook.com/ads/manager/billing/transactions)
is there any way for that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that endpoint is not a part of the public API. Officially, it can only be accessed through the Ads Manager. And while accessing private API is certainly possible, it's also a great way to risk account suspension.